# Using JavaScript: Using a modal class when i am editing a specific html table row. how to select the current value on a dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript

I am new in this!

I have a table of content with the tag [Name, Gender and Age]. When editing a line, using the modal class, the dropdownlist doesn't take the select table value as the default value on the dropdownlist, it will show it empty.

Tx!

AC

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-edit">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form action="page.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <input name="item0" id="item0" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control select2" name="item1" id="item1" >
                <option></option>
                <option>Female</option>
                <option>Male</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <input name="item2" id="item2" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="Submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `@Ava` I found `select2` class in select tag so i think you are using `select2 plugin` so it will not automatically selected on edit more so you will need to **refresh** `select2 class` when modal open then you can see `selected gender` value.

Comment: @raeesh, i took it of (select 2) but it didn't work anyway. To catch the table values I am using the script below: 
`<Script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.editbtn').on('click', function (){
       $('#modal-edit').modal('show'); 
        
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        
        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        
        $('#item0').val(data[0]);
        $('#item1').val(data[1]);
        $('#item2').val(data[2]);
    });
});
</Script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want show default value in drop down like this.
add value for each option in select box and make one option selected by add **selected** attribute.

```
 <select class="form-control select2" name="item1" id="item1" >
                <option selected>Please Select Gender</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
            </select>
```

**edited**

```
<script>
var gender='male'; // you variable may have value 'male' or 'female'
$('#item1').val(gender);
```

Comment: I want to show the default gender value previously selected to be edited. I don't know if i made my self clear.

Comment: if you want to select it will be using $('#item1').val('male')

Comment: instead of male pass you variable.  
see edited answer

Comment: Tx! i tried @Raeesh example, it worked. Anyway I'll try it and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Check my snippet and its working fine as your need & instructions with using of `select2` plugin for drop-down `Gender` selection.
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.select2').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1 //Search field hide
  });
});

$('#modal-edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  // e.relatedTarget -> to find which button clicked
  var getName = $(e.relatedTarget).parents()[1].cells[0].innerText;
  var getGender = $(e.relatedTarget).parents()[1].cells[1].innerText;
  var getAge = $(e.relatedTarget).parents()[1].cells[2].innerText;

  $('#item0').val(getName);
  $('#item1').val(getGender);
  $('#item2').val(getAge);

  $(".select2").select2({minimumResultsForSearch: -1}); //after value set in drop-down list then again reinitialize
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th width="120">Action</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Ricky</td>
       <td>Male</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp;Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Mikolo</td>
       <td>Female</td>
       <td>38</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp;Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Simora</td>
       <td>Female</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp;Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Raeesh</td>
       <td>Male</td>
       <td>29</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp;Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Yuvraj</td>
       <td>Male</td>
       <td>37</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp;Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-edit">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="'.$page.'" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10"> 
               <input name="item0" id="item0" class="form-control">
              </div>
           </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select class="form-control select2" name="item1" id="item1" data-width="100%">
                 <option value="Female">Female</option>
                 <option value="Male">Male</option>
              </select>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <input name="item2" id="item2" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="Submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save & Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```